# How much computationally expensive is Matrix multiplication?

Tags: performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication, computation

What advantage does the function

```
N(x;θ) = θ1(θ2*x)
```

has over

```
G(x;θ) = θ*x
```

for an input vector

```
x ∈ R^n
θ1 ∈ R^(nx1)
θ2 ∈ R^(1xn)
θ ∈ R^(nxn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first case, θ2 with dimension 1xn is multiplied with x with dimension n. That gives output of 1x1. Then multiplied by nx1 the output dimension of N(x;θ) is nx1. So there are n elements in θ2 and n elements in θ1. In total there are n+n (2n) elements.

For second case, θ with dimension nxn is multiplied with x with dimension n. That gives output dimension for G(x;θ) as nx1. In this case there are n*n (n^2) elements for θ.

Therefore, the advantage is that, it is computationally inexpensive to calculate the first case then the second case.